# YAML Syntax Highlighting

Tags: listings

The `listings` package does not support [YAML](http://yaml.org/) out of the box. Does a package exist that extends `listings` with YAML support? More generally, is there a good listing somewhere of extensions to `listings`?

Comment: The »[minted](http://ctan.org/pkg/minted)« package supports YAML indirectly by its back-end Python Pygments.

Comment: Which yaml? The [css framework](http://www.yaml.de/) or the [markup language](http://yaml.org/)?

Comment: @knut The markup language.  Didn't even know the CSS framework existed!

Comment: @ThorstenDonig Thanks Thorsten, this works. You should make it an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152829/lstdefinelanguage-for-yaml

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The »[minted](http://ctan.org/pkg/minted)« package is your friend here. It uses Python Pygments as back-end for syntax highlighting. And one of the Pygments lexers is for YAML. An approach how to get a YAML script formatted could look like this.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
  \section{The YAML Language}
  \begin{minted}[
    gobble=4,
    frame=single,
    linenos
  ]{yaml}
    --- !clarkevans.com/^invoice
    invoice: 34843
    date   : 2001-01-23
    bill-to: &id001
        given  : Chris
        family : Dumars
        address:
            lines: |
                458 Walkman Dr.
                Suite #292
            city    : Royal Oak
            state   : MI
            postal  : 48046
    ship-to: *id001
    product:
        - sku         : BL394D
          quantity    : 4
          description : Basketball
          price       : 450.00
        - sku         : BL4438H
          quantity    : 1
          description : Super Hoop
          price       : 2392.00
    tax  : 251.42
    total: 4443.52
    comments: >
        Late afternoon is best.
        Backup contact is Nancy
        Billsmer @ 338-4338.
  \end{minted}
\end{document}
```

For details about the package and further options for customization please refer to its [manual](https://yaml.org).

---

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, [Pygments highlights very little in the way of YAML syntax](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/issues/890/yaml-highlight), and it is hard to configure otherwise.  [Using the `listings` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152856/22603) might be a better idea if you want keys and values to be in different colours.

Comment: Would it be possible to decrease space in between lines?

Comment: Shared script link is dead

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336919/simple-coloring-of-json-attributes) for JSON, I implemented a similar style with for YAML with the listings package:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{yaml}{
     basicstyle=\color{blue}\footnotesize,
     rulecolor=\color{black},
     string=[s]{'}{'},
     stringstyle=\color{blue},
     comment=[l]{:},
     commentstyle=\color{black},
     morecomment=[l]{-}
 }

\begin{lstlisting}[style=yaml]
  hello: world
  info:
    title: hello
    version: world
  components:
    - This is a member
\end{lstlisting}
```

The result:

[image]

It works by setting the default color (`basicstyle`) to blue, and then marking everything else as comments. For example,`comment=[l]{:}` will mark as a comment the rest of a line (`[l]`) after a semicolon (`{:}`)