# How can I highlight YAML code in a pretty way with listings?

Tags: listings, highlighting

I'm trying to highlight simple YAML (the markup language, not the CSS framework) code. I know that there is a solution using pygments and minted, however, I would prefer a solution with `\lstdefinelanguage`.

This is my code so far:

```
\lstdefinelanguage{yaml}{
  keywords={true,false,null,y,n},
  keywordstyle=\color{darkgray}\bfseries,
  ndkeywords={},
  ndkeywordstyle=\color{black}\bfseries,
  identifierstyle=\color{black},
  sensitive=false,
  %moredelim=[l]{}{:},
  comment=[l]{#},
  morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
  commentstyle=\color{purple}\ttfamily,
  stringstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily,
  %morestring=[l]{-}{},
  morestring=[b]',
  morestring=[b]"
}
```

Two things are missing, though:

1. I would like to print all keys bold
2. I would like to print all strings, also the ones without qotes, to be blue.

I tried to accomplish these two things with the commented lines in the code above. Unfortunately, they did not work. Any suggestions on how I can make this work?

Here is a small YAML example:

```
key: value
map:
    key1: value1
    key2: value2
list:
  - element1
  - element2
# This is a comment
listOfMaps:
  - key1: value1a
    key2: value1b
  - key1: value2a
    key2: value2b
```

This is the output I currently get:

[image]

Comment: Could you define "all strings, also the ones without quotes"?  I'm not familiar with YAML and from the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) I cannot understand what other strings there are, apart from those in single or double quotes.

Comment: I had a bad experience with `listings` and YAML in a manual I wrote; I used some delimiters in order to achieve syntax highlighting, but it's quite messy. Take a look at `minted`, it relies on `pygments` under the hood and it has built-in YAML support.

Comment: Unfortunately, because YAML uses no delimiters for its keys, you'll have a hard time implementing the key style you want. One solution would be to declare all the key names you use as `listings`' `keywords`, and set the style for those keywords as you wish. Not a very satisfying solution but viable if the number of distinct key names is small.

Comment: @nickie Sorry for not being clear on that. In YAML, the types of values are inferred and thus, strings are mostly not enclosed by quotes. `key: value` and `key: "value"` are equivalent, `value` is a string for both. I would like to color strings, either with or without quotes, in the same color. I hope, this makes it clear.

Comment: @Jubobs I might consider that as a fallback. And thanks for the edit.

Comment: @str Based on what I just read, `key: value` and `key: "value"` are indeed equivalent, but a value can only contain colon(s) if it's delimited by double quotes (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783705/how-could-should-i-state-colon-punctuation-in-a-yaml-file).

Comment: @Jubobs Yes there are some cases where quotes are required, but in other cases they can be left away.

Comment: @str I only mentioned it because it complicates the parsing of the YAML code (for pretty-printing it) even further.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here is a partial solution involving some juggling with the `literate` and `moredelim` keys. The values, if delimited by double quotes, can contain colons.

**Caveat**: values that span multiple lines won't be correctly highlighted.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand\YAMLcolonstyle{\color{red}\mdseries}
\newcommand\YAMLkeystyle{\color{black}\bfseries}
\newcommand\YAMLvaluestyle{\color{blue}\mdseries}

\makeatletter

% here is a macro expanding to the name of the language
% (handy if you decide to change it further down the road)
\newcommand\language@yaml{yaml}

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\lstdefinelanguage
\expandafter{\language@yaml}
{
  keywords={true,false,null,y,n},
  keywordstyle=\color{darkgray}\bfseries,
  basicstyle=\YAMLkeystyle,                                 % assuming a key comes first
  sensitive=false,
  comment=[l]{\#},
  morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
  commentstyle=\color{purple}\ttfamily,
  stringstyle=\YAMLvaluestyle\ttfamily,
  moredelim=[l][\color{orange}]{\&},
  moredelim=[l][\color{magenta}]{*},
  moredelim=**[il][\YAMLcolonstyle{:}\YAMLvaluestyle]{:},   % switch to value style at :
  morestring=[b]',
  morestring=[b]",
  literate =    {---}{{\ProcessThreeDashes}}3
                {>}{{\textcolor{red}\textgreater}}1     
                {|}{{\textcolor{red}\textbar}}1 
                {\ -\ }{{\mdseries\ -\ }}3,
}

% switch to key style at EOL
\lst@AddToHook{EveryLine}{\ifx\lst@language\language@yaml\YAMLkeystyle\fi}
\makeatother

\newcommand\ProcessThreeDashes{\llap{\color{cyan}\mdseries-{-}-}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=yaml]
---
key: value
map:
    key1: "foo:bar"
    key2: value2
list:
  - element1
  - element2
# This is a comment
listOfMaps:
  - key1: value1a
    key2: value1b
  - key1: value2a
    key2: value2b
---
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
some
other
listing
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, it's awesome! :)`

Comment: Is there any way to make that `\lst@AddToHook{EOL}{\YAMLkeystyle}` be `yaml`-specific? As of now, it's destroying the highlighting for other languages as well: http://i.stack.imgur.com/28HCE.png

Comment: @SeanAllred See my edit.

Comment: Can we decrease additinal space in between lines?