# Listings: highlighting key-value file?

Tags: listings

Say I have the following key-value file I want to highlight using the listings package:

```
some.key=Some value
```

I want the key to be red, the equal sign to be black and the value to be blue. How do I define a language in listings that does that? I am aware of the `moredelim`, `morekeywords` but I can't figure out how to use their options to do what I want.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Perhaps there is a language that uses this syntax?

Comment: @SeanAllred: Perhaps the language is `TeX` or `LaTeX` itself?

Comment: It may be possible. It depends on the language you're using. What is it? Could you post a longer code sample and  list all your syntax highlighting specs? Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81646/how-can-i-highlight-text-before-a-character-with-listing, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152829/lstdefinelanguage-for-yaml

Comment: @Christian Perhaps, but I would be at least a little surprised if it took keyval syntax into account. (Does the PGF manual use listings?)

Comment: @Jubobs I think those links answered my questions. It seems the real problem here is how to highlight the key automatically without hardcoding it as a keyword in listings. And it seems like the answer in general is: not possible. Too bad

Comment: @SeanAllred: I have used `listings` only for `c` or `c++` code so far, I can't tell about `TeX` support or even keyval syntax.

Comment: @johnrl Should we close this question as a duplicate?

Comment: @Jubobs yes please