# How can I typeset JSON code with the listings package?

Tags: listings, json

I got this error with the `listings` package (v 1.5c). Should I install the language manually?

```
! Package Listings Error: Couldn't load requested language.

See the Listings package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.161 ...{lstlisting}[language=json,firstnumber=1]
```

This is my TeX version running on Mac OSX 10.9.5.

```
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2014)
kpathsea version 6.2.0
```

Comment: `See the Listings package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.` Unlike many error messages, this one is actually helpful!

Comment: You're getting an error because [`listings` doesn't define any language called `json`](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/macros/latex/contrib/listings/lstdrvrs.dtx). In fact, if you want to typeset JSON code, you need to set `listings` up yourself for that. Either provide your own language definition for JSON, or build upon others' settings; see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83085/how-to-improve-listings-display-of-json-files) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195540/21891), for instance.