# Simple coloring of json attributes

Tags: listings, json

Could someone please explain me how I can color the json attributes for a json string in listing? An example would be great. Thanks.

Example String: {"name1":"attribute1","name2":"attribute2"}. How can I make the string "name1" and "name2" appear blue?

I tried the solution at 
[How can I highlight JSON string values but not attributes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195486/how-can-i-highlight-json-string-values-but-not-attributes) but this highlights the values and not the attributes.

Comment: Could you give a minimum working example of what you've tried? This question doesn't make sense in the context of TeX yet.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152829/how-can-i-highlight-yaml-code-in-a-pretty-way-with-listings

Comment: @Ryan: sorry just updated it in the question.

Comment: For complex highlighting requirements, minted might be worth to consider.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a trick way: Highlight all strings except those following a colon.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\begin{document}

\lstset{
    string=[s]{"}{"},
    stringstyle=\color{blue},
    comment=[l]{:},
    commentstyle=\color{black},
}
\begin{lstlisting}
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "isAlive": true,
  "age": 25,
  "height_cm": 167.6,
  "address": {
    "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "postalCode": "10021-3100"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type": "home",
      "number": "212 555-1234"
    },
    {
      "type": "office",
      "number": "646 555-4567"
    }
  ]
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

PS: Internally, the following aspects `strings`, `comments`, `escape`, `style`, `language`, `keywords`, `labels`, `lineshape`, `frames`, `emph`, `index` are treat equally. In case you need `string`/`comment` for the actual string/comment, you can add an aspect's dealing with attributes and values by yourself.

Comment: It doesn't work when the attribute-value pairs are in the same line. In the {"name1":"attribute1","name2":"attribute2"} example, only name1 is highlighted.

Comment: It is hard to guarantee anything: [tag:listings] is not automata, it cannot remember if this string is before `:` or after `:` or the presence of `,`. In your example, you might want to try `comment=[s]{:\ "}{"}` or `comment=[s]{:"}{"}`.

Comment: (And if you take a look at how [tag:listings] deals with other fancier languages, e.g. C/HTML/..., you will find that most of the time it just brutally collects all possible keywords, and the declaration of the language is pathetically long...)

Comment: Your last comment helped. I have same set of attributes for all the json strings. So I added the entire list of attributes to "morekeywords".  Thank you.