# LATEX - How to write \lstdefinestyle for the YAML language

Tags: pdftex, listings

Starting from the answer to this question [YAML Syntax Highlighting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145504/yaml-syntax-highlighting/657205#657205).

If I wanted to have "- name:" colored blue and not black, and "test" colored in blue, how is this possible?

```yaml
spec:
 containers:
  - name: test
```

Answer (score 4):

I needed to achieve a similar result, for a docker-compose YAML, and it was not immediate to find an answer. Anyway, this is a method that could allow you to achieve a result similar to the desired one:

- Define a custom language similar to the following

```latex
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstdefinelanguage{my-yaml}{
  keywords={spec, containers, name}, % ,... all the keyword you want
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
  moredelim=[is][commentstyle]{||}{££}, % invisible custom delimiters
  identifierstyle=\color{black},
  sensitive=false,
  comment=[l]{\#},
  commentstyle=\color{olive}\ttfamily,
  stringstyle=\color{orange}\ttfamily,
  morestring=[b]',
  morestring=[b]"
}
```

- use it as follows

```latex
\begin{lstlisting}[language=my-yaml,caption={Docker Compose YAML composing the various containers of the setup together.},numbers=left]
spec:
 containers:
  - name: ||test££
\end{lstlisting}
```

This is the end result:
[image: end result]

Comment: nice +1 . You're on a good track