# How to properly format an included docker-compose.yml file

Tags: code, syntax-highlighting, docker

How do I properly format and highlight a `docker-compose.yml` file when including a code snippet into a latex document.

I want to do something like:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=YAML}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting{docker-compose.yml}

\end{document}
```

to import the following `docker-compose.yml`.

```yml
version: "3.7"

services:
  foo:
    image: hello-world
```

How do I add syntax highlighting for `*.yaml`/`*.yml` files?

I am aware of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145504/yaml-syntax-highlighting) to format a yaml snippet.
I want to know how to do the same with an imported yaml file.

Comment: Please make a compilable minimal working example which shows us your class, the relevant packages and a short test document. Please also include what the result should look like - formatted properly can mean many things ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same approach as in the answer you linked to (don't forget to also load the `xcolor` package):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{yaml}{
     basicstyle=\color{blue}\footnotesize,
     rulecolor=\color{black},
     string=[s]{'}{'},
     stringstyle=\color{blue},
     comment=[l]{:},
     commentstyle=\color{black},
     morecomment=[l]{-}
 }


\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[style=yaml]{docker-compose.yml}

\end{document}
```

[image]